# How to uninstall GDB from MacOS?

Tags: gdb, uninstallation

I didn't use `brew` to install so `brew uninstall` doesn't work for me. Instead, I download a specific version of zip file from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/, then

```
./configure
make
sudo make install,
```

to install GDB on my /usr/local/bin. I want to try another version right now. Could anyone tell me how to remove this GDB completely from my computer? Thanks in advance!